# How to change the background color of an Excel report

Tags: excel, powershell

Basically, I am using this script to run through all the `.csv` files in a specific folder and merge them all together. But after the merge, I still want to change the background color of each `.csv` file.

The script that I got so far does not do that, can't figure out how to do it as I am really new in PowerShell.

```
# Get all the information from .csv files that are in the $IN_FILE_PATH skipping the first line:
$getFirstLine = $true

get-childItem "$IN_FILE_PATH\*.csv" | ForEach {
    $filePath = $_

    $lines = $lines = Get-Content $filePath
    $linesToWrite = switch ($getFirstLine) {
        $true { $lines }
        $false { $lines | Select -Skip 1 }
    }

    # Import all the information... and tranfer to the new workbook.
    $Report_name = $((get-date).ToString("yyyy.MM.dd-hh.mm"))

    $getFirstLine = $false
    Add-Content "$OUT_FILE_PATH\Report $Report_Name.csv" $linesToWrite
}
```

e.g. The `.csv` file has this pattern:

> ```
> Name        Age
>
> Richard     18
> Carlos      20
> Jonathan    43
> Mathew      25
> ```

Making sure to understand that Richard (18 years old) and Carlos (20 years old) are from `filenumber1.csv` - Jonathan (43 years old) and Mathew (25 years old) are from `filenumber2.csv`

I want Carlos' and Richard's rows to be with a white background, whereas Jonathan's and Mathew's rows to be grey. So that repeats in white-grey-white-grey dividing it by each file.
I am trying to make it more friendly to observe the report in the end - to make sure that you can this separation from file to file more clear.

Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot add formatting to a `.csv` file. Better use an `xlsx`/an excel sheet.

Comment: I can do that. But all the files have to come as .csv - maybe I can get them to change to .xlsx and perform the changes so that afterward I can merge them as .csv again. But anyways... I still don't know how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Vivek Kumar Singh mentioned in comments, `.csv` doesn't contain any formatting options. It's recommended to work with Excel file instead. And for that purpose, the best module I know and use is [ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel).

The code to set formatting is as below (inspired by [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/e675bd5b-1f13-410d-83c2-cf042125cfd5/how-do-i-export-the-results-into-an-excel-spreadsheet-and-highlight-the-results-in-green-once-the?forum=winserverpowershell)):

```bsh
$IN_FILE_PATH = "C:\SO\56870016"
# mkdir $IN_FILE_PATH
# cd $IN_FILE_PATH
# rm out.xlsx

# Define colors
$colors = "White", "Gray"

# Initialization
$colorsTable = @()
$data = @()
$n = 0

Get-ChildItem "$IN_FILE_PATH\*.csv"  | % {
  $part = Import-Csv $_
  $data += $part
  for ($i = 0; $i -lt ($part).Count; $i++) {
    $colorsTable += $colors[$n%2]
  }
  $n++
}


$j = 0
$data | Export-Excel .\out.xlsx -WorksheetName "Output" -Append -CellStyleSB {
  param(
    $workSheet,
    $totalRows,
    $lastColumn
  )        

  foreach($row in (2..$totalRows )) {
    # The magic happens here
    # We set colors based on the list which was created while importing
    Set-CellStyle $workSheet $row $LastColumn Solid $colorsTable[$j]
    $j++
  }        
}
```

Hopefully the comments in the code help you to better understanding of what's going on in the code.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately, I am not able to change it to .xlsx - I need it in .csv 

And it makes sense to me now that .csv does not contain formatting options. Thanks.